# socket.io performance with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

So, I have a node.js server which receives data from mobile phones (GPS).The server although make some calculation to find out the speed or the distance. 
I'm using socket.IO to transport the data, and I visualize them with a web-client.

Here is my issue : When i simulate 500 mobile phones, the sockets are going down. I can visualize my data only for a few seconds on the web page before the sockets crash. 
I read some article like this one : https://bocoup.com/weblog/node-stress-test-analysis/
The author is able to open 10000 client... So I don't understand why I can't !

Anybody knows what is the problem ?

Thanks

Edit

Server : 4096 Mo memory and 1 vCPU.

Server code :

```
 var app = express();    

// creation
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var httpsIO = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer); 

// config du port
// HTTP
var port = 8080;

server.listen(port);
```

Sockets :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(server) 
{

    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    io.sockets.setMaxListeners(0);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var d;
        var address = socket.handshake.address;
        socket.emit('connection_ok');

        socket.on('join', function (ids) {
            var datas = new Array();
            if(ids.split(' ').length > 1)
            {
                var coureur_id = ids.split(' ').shift();
                var course_id = ids.split(' ').pop();
                participant(coureur_id, course_id, function(coureur_id, course_id, date)
                {
                    d = date;
                    socket.emit('ack', coureur_id);
                    socket.join(coureur_id);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var course_id = ids;
                getParticipants(course_id, function(participants)
                {
                    if(participants != null)
                    {
                        for(var j=0; j<participants.length; j++)
                        {
                    socket.join(participants[j].user_id)
                        }
                    }
                });         
            }




              // Mobil phone update the position
              socket.on('commit', function (pos) 
              {
                var fini = false;
                if (pos) 
                {
                    if (pos['latitude'] && pos['longitude']) 
                    {
                        if (pos['speed'] != undefined) 
                        {
                            if (pos['distance'] != undefined) 
                            {   
                                // datas sent to the database (mongoDB)
                              addCoureurData(coureur_id, course_id, pos, d, datas, fini, function(res)
                                    {

                                      datas = res.datas;
                                      var classement = res.classement;
                                      pourcentAccompli(course_id,coureur_id,pos, datas, function(result)
                                      {
                                        socket.broadcast.to(coureur_id).emit('update', { user : coureur_id, latitude : pos['latitude'], longitude : pos['longitude'], vitesse : pos['speed'], distance : pos['distance'], classement : classement, pourcent : result});
                                      });
                                    });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
               });
          });
     });
}
```

Comment: Depends what you're sending. Depends how good your connection is. Depends on how powerful your server is. You need to give more information in my opinion, such as code.

Comment: Can we see a sample of the data, and the code of the client side, and server side socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is nothing inherently wrong in the code design, the number of concurrent connections your server can handle will vary based on a multitude of factors. RAM allocated to your node app, open file limits (if the file system is involved), and general hardware setup are just some of the important factors. Also, the kind of processing that is actually taking place server-side will influence the concurrent connection threshold.

Comment: Well, i make a lot of calculation everytime the sockets send data (every two seconds for me). So it could be that... I tried with 4 vCPU but it didnt change anything.